# Add a "Cloud drive available for mount" link to nautilus

Tags: mount, nautilus, cloud

Nautilus default interface includes a list of "mountable" drives (eg. plugged USB drives). Click it to mount then access the contents, right click > eject to unmount. Once you add a google account to Nautilus general config, this list also includes the associated google drive.

I'm using [mega.nz](https://mega.nz), and configured [rclone](https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_mount/) to mount it via `rclone mount --daemon`. Could I "add it" to nautilus so that I can mount/unmount it with a click instead of opening the terminal each time?

Bonus: is it also possible to add it in the gnome sidebar, like USB drives do (but google drive accounts don't)

Comment: It may or may not help, but nautilus seems to be using gvfs, which apparently has no support for rclone nor mega.nz, but has one for FUSE. Maybe FUSE could interface with rclone, or directly to mega.nz??

Comment: Not quite as perfect, but you could set up a nautilus script or create a launcher if you want to avoid having to open the terminal.